# excel 2007 Workbook_open not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear Print Area And Autofilter when excel opens:
Am total novice in  Excel vba so Assmebled the followingcode from googling around
This code I have put in ThisWorkbook of Personal.xlsb in the XLstart folder and ofcourse the macro security has been set to enable all macros

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents xlApp As Excel.Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set xlApp = Application
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Close()
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call ClrPrntArea
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Here is the ClrPrntArea

```
Sub ClrPrntArea()
Dim ws As Object


For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
    With Worksheets(i)
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
        .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

I will also be putting another macro call to module in personal xlsb for resetting the autofiter once  above starts working..Any inputs will be really helpfull

Comment: Why do you need to have a new instance of Excel and open the workbook using that instance? What is the use of turning on/off `EnableEvents`?

Comment: Hey Kalpesh ,I am under impression that we need to enable events to perform some action on Worksheets...

Comment: No, that is not necessary. Events are a hook for one to write code for some method invoked on an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `PERSONAL.xlsb`, module `ThisWorkbook`, try the below; it's nearly the same code as in your request, with some modif's:

- application object declared Private
- event routine uses the local `WB` object variable handed over as parameter, instead of the `ActiveWorkbook` object
- replaced `For ... Next` by `For Each ... Next` and working with local object variables
- trap processing of `PERSONAL.xlsb` itself

Once you're happy remove all the MsgBox statements (and the `Else`), they are just to show what is happening and when.

```
Private WithEvents Excel_App As Excel.Application

' runs when Excel_App encounters a Workbook_Open() event
Private Sub Excel_App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal WB As Workbook)
Dim WS As Worksheet

    If WB.Name <> "PERSONAL.xlsb" Then
        MsgBox "PERSONAL.xlsb: Excel_App_WorkbookOpen(): " & WB.Name
        For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
            WS.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
            WS.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
            If WS.FilterMode Then
                WS.ShowAllData
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "PERSONAL.xlsb: Excel_App_WorkbookOpen(): myself"
    End If
End Sub

' runs when PERSONAL.xlsb is opened
' assign current Excel application to object variable Excel_App
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "PERSONAL.xlsb: Workbook_Open()"
    Set Excel_App = Application
End Sub
```

*Note*:

When the event handler doesn't start when you **double-click** an Excel file (e.g. on your desktop), close all Excel applications and inspect the task manager for additional orphaned Excel processes which need to be killed. It happened to me while playing around with this code

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply Mike...But when I put the above code in my Personal.xlsm it get the runtime error 91 :Object Variable or With Block variable not set..When I do the debug for this It points the line  "    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count" and I try to Run this without any edits from VB Editor and it works fine...ANy thoughts?

Comment: hmm I seem not to be able to reproduce this error 91; I edited my answer and provided the full code I tested

Comment: Hey Mike When I implement your code Now I get the Runtime error 9 subscript out of range at this line         With Worksheets(i)...

Comment: Can you please edit your question and paste your complete code

Comment: I used the Same Code that you posted:                                                                  Option Explicit

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Integer
    Stop                                          ' go into        debugging mode
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(i)
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
            .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData      ' if in filtered mode, show all
        End With
    Next
    End Sub

Comment: I have a stupit question now .... do you have at least one worksheet in your file? Otherwise I couldn't explain why the subscript goes out of range.

Comment: Yes all the workbooks I have opened Contain at least one worksheet.Did you mean the Personal.xlsb file located in XLstart?

Comment: ayeeehhhhhh .... I now understand that the macro is in `...\XLStart\ Personal.xlsb` but you want to execute this macro when you open other workbooks and you want this macro to process that other workbooks you open ???

Comment: Yes Mike You are Spot On ..I want all the macros in Personal.xlsb to process any workbook that is opened...

Comment: Sorry for my misinterpretation ... so I need to re-write my answer ... pse stand by for 1 hour or so ... I'm in a meeting

Comment: Mike You got  Chance to look at some possible solution